# Texturing a moving mask in Unity URP

Tags: unity-game-engine, urp, shader-graph

I am trying to create an unlit shader graph in unity for a simple plane object that works like an X-ray showing position of a target object passing behind it by masking it into a sphere.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGp8D.png)

Everything works fine until I try to texture it with something like a crosshair or something else where the mask is placed. Mask moves but the texture on the plane doesn't so it looks like someone holding spotlight over a textured wall. I want to texture the mask or move the texture with the mask.

Is there a valid and clean way to accomplish this. The screenshot of my simple shader is added

Thanks in advance to anyone who contributes.